# Need to send and recieve data to an arduino via 5-10m CAT6 away from each othere

Tags: pi-zero, arduino

Hello I would like to know if there is already a protocol that both the raspberry pi zero and the arduino (nano) have in common that i can use to communicate 5-10 meters away no added hardware? With the raspberry pi acting as the master.

I would like to retriev a 24bit data from the nano, and also would like to send a 1 bit data to the nano but that is pretty simple to achieve i can just use any GPIO for that.

Comment: You mention CAT6 which is ethernet cable but the nano has no ethernet unless there is "added hardware".   What they do both have is a UART and an I2C bus, but I dunno about the length of the wires. WRT 24-bit data, you cannot do that in parallel, there aren't enough pins.   Serialized you can send whatever data you like.

Comment: @goldilocks yes CAT6 but without the RJ45 terminations. Should be good for signals because of they are twisted pairs.

Comment: What's wrong with using a serial port?

Comment: I do not need very high speeds, google says at 10khz i2c can go for 10m, but not tested though. The RS protocols is my supposed go to but the connectors form factor are to big, theres also no board i can get easily that lets me just screw in in wires

Comment: @Seamus how far can serial port go ? Dont you need special chips if you want to go with longer wires?

Comment: How far?... How high is the sky? There are several variables that determine this. But in the time it's taken you to ask these questions, you could have already tried something. [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port), then go forth and experiment.

Answer (score 1):

how about an i2c extender. Have a look at [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/qwiic-differential-i2c-bus-extender-pca9615-hookup-guide/all)
Otherwise look for something in the 485 neighborhood. I haven't tested i2c over 4-5 meters so I can't really say if it will work without extra equipment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an UART, either via a 3-wire cable (TX, RX and GND) or wireless via modules such as HC-11 (though that is added hardware). You could use an Enthernet cable for that: one twisted pair carries TX/RX, and the rest of the wires carry GND.